# How to get JSON Data from multiple url in same thread using loop or any other way

Tags: ios, json

I want to get data from different url in same thread. How can i do that.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject];

for(int i=0;i<[url count];i++){
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url[i]];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error != nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                       }
                                                       else{
                                                           // If no error occurs, check the HTTP status code.
                                                           NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

                                                           // If it's other than 200, then show it on the console.
                                                           if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
                                                               NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %d", HTTPStatusCode);
                                                           }

                                                           // Call the completion handler with the returned data on the main thread.
                                                           [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                                               completionHandler(data);
                                                           }];
                                                       }


                                                   }];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

i want to get all value ..If i get that than i will save each url value in an array

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same thread". You want to be notified when the 5 values are fetched ?

Comment: i want to get value from each Url in same session ? is it possible ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you want to achieve ^^